# Append text to a line on multiple conditions

Tags: sed

I am very new to sed so please bear with me... I have a file with contents like

```
a=1
b=2,3,4
c=3
d=8
.
.
```

I want to append 'x' to a line which starts with 'c=' and does not contain an 'x'. What I am using right now is

```
sed -i '/^c=/ s/$/x/'
```

but this does not cover the second part of my explanation, the 'x' should only be appended if the line did not have it already and hence if I run the command twice it makes the line "c=3xx" which I do not want.

Any help here would be highly appreciated and I know there are a lot of sharp heads around here :) I understand that this can be handled pretty easily through bash but using sed here is a hard requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
sed -i '/^c=/ {/x/b; s/$/x/}'
```

Curly brackets are used for grouping. The `b` command branches to the end of the script (stops the processing of the current line).

```
   b label
          Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
```

Edit: as William Pursell suggests in the comment, a shorter version would be

```
sed -i '/^c=/ { /x/ !s/$/x/ }'
```

Comment: nice answer to a nice question

Comment: Probably cleaner to write `'/^c=/{/x/!s/$/x/}'`

Comment: Very neat :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is probably a better choice here as you can easily combine regular expression matches with logical operators. Given the input:

```
$ cat file
a=1
b=2,3,4
c=3
c=x
c=3
d=8
```

The command would be:

```
$ awk '/^c=/ && !/x/ {$0=$0"x"; print $0}' file
a=1
b=2,3,4
c=3x
c=x
c=3x
d=8
```

Where `$0` is the `awk` variable that contains the current line being read.

Comment: yes and @LevLevitsky provides a great `sed` solution. It would be a shame everybody was as narrow minded as you on stackoverflow, my answer shows a different *(correct)* solution.

Comment: I don't do this often, but, I have learned this from people like you. I am fine to undo the downvote. It is locked, so can't do much unless you change your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^c=[^x]*$/s/$/x/' file
```

or:

```
sed -i 's/^c=[^x]*$/&x/' file
```